# How to do pattern matching and parsing strings in javascript without regex

Tags: node.js, bots

I am writing a bot in Node and would like an easy way to match *AND* parse incoming requests. I would like to do something similar to this:

```
var message = "What's the weather in Timbuktu?"; //comes from bot
var patterns = [];
patterns.push({intent:"weather", pattern:"[what's|what is|how's|how is|][the|]weather[in|]{?location}"}];
patterns.push({intent:"time", pattern:"[what's|what is|what][the|]time[is it in|in|]{?location}"}];
var result= getIntent(patterns, message);
```

In this example, the expected value of result would be:

```
{intent:'weather', data:{location:'Timbuktu'}}
```

I've done a bit a digging for such a beast, but most solutions involve regex.  I'm not totally opposed to that, but think in this case something simpler and more human-readable would be better.  This is similar to how Amazon Alexa parses utterances, but I'm hoping for something generic that could be used with various bot APIs.  [alexa-utterances](https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-utterances) comes close, but is only for expanding the pattern, not parsing and providing the slot values.

Comment: I'd suggest going for a PhD program, then researching this topic for several years, if not your entire career.

Comment: @torazaburo is almost right. This topic is called Natural Language Processing (or NLP for short). It is currently a growing multi-million dollar industry but there's also lots of free solutions. Google "natural language processing". In fact google has an API for it. Most solutions you'll find are cloud based because most of them are backed by huge databases. Human language is just not simple to parse and English is not one of the easier ones.

Comment: I've tinkered with some of the NLP stuff, but in my mind this is simpler than that.  I don't need to truly understand the sentence structure, etc- "just" pattern match and pull out values. Regex, but simpler and easier to read?  Maybe I'm oversimplifying though?

Comment: @torazaburo It would be easy to perform this task using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html), but I haven't yet found a similar tool for JavaScript.